# Tree Search using a SQL Query to find Common Cells

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I will like to do is to retrieve all the persons that contain two common columns (movie and year):

```
login_id | movie               | year
---------|---------------------|-----------
john     | the matrix          | 1999
john     | star wars           | 1977
bob      | titanic             | 1997
johnny   | the matrix          | 1999
tony     | lord of the rings   | 2001
tony     | lord of the rings   | 2002
tony     | lord of the rings   | 2003
james    | star wars           | 1977
robert   | star trek           | 1966
james    | titanic             | 1997
bob      | star trek           | 1966
...
```

So if am interested in finding for `login_id: bob` what movies he watched plus who else watched the same movies expected output:

```
login_id | movie               | year
---------|---------------------|-----------
james    | titanic             | 1997
robert   | star trek           | 1966
...
```

I want to do it efficiently as possible and if I need to restructure the table I will do it. First guess:

`SELECT login_id, movie, year, count(*)
 FROM watchers
 GROUP BY login_id, movie, year
 HAVING count(*) > 1 **and login_id = 'bob'**`

The 'and' is where I am confuse, because it is grouping by count instead of pulling out all the common data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking `exists`:

```
select w.*
from watchers w
where exists (select 1
              from watchers w2
              where w2.movie = w.movie and w2.year = w.year and w2.login_id = 'bob'
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a self join:

```
Select t1.*
From  table t0
Join table t1 on t0.movie = t1.movie
And t0.year = t1.year
Where t0.login_id ='bob'
```